# Laravel Queue: How to set a persistent database connection

Tags: mysql, laravel, queue, laravel-6, persistent

I wonder if there is a way to set a `persistent database connection` in Laravel Queues? Ive setup the queue connection via database and I dont want it to connection every few seconds to poll for new jobs.

This is the connection settings ive got now:

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'connection' => 'mysql',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 190,
    'block_for' => 0,
],
```

Comment: What do you mean by `" I don't want it to connection every few seconds to poll for new jobs."`?

Comment: Considering there is not much mentioned in the documentation on how it works, I assume it will pull from `jobs` table every few seconds in a loop to find next job to perform.

Comment: You have to run a queue worker which will listen for dispatch events. When a job is dispatched, a worker is assigned to it and the worker is responsible for the next job, if any. **There is no loop.**

Comment: The jobs are saved in the Jobs table right? So eventually somebody is checking it every few seconds, either worker or event manager